# Nginx, how to add header if it is not set

Tags: caching, header, nginx, http-headers

I want to add a header (`Cache-control`) in nginx only if it is not set.

I need to increase cache time in some case via the header in nginx.

Comment: Same question for me, and this question does not have any valuable answer. I want to add a X-correlationId header with an uuid if it is not already set. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 26):

You can use `map` to populate a variable `$cachecontrol`. If `$http_cache_control` (the header from the client) is empty, set a custom value. Otherwise (default) reuse the value from the client.

```
map $http_cache_control $cachecontrol {
    default   $http_cache_control;
    ""        "public, max-age=31536000";
}
```

Afterwards you can use that variable to send the upstream header.

```
proxy_set_header X-Request-ID $cachecontrol;
```

---

For the follow-up question from [jmcollin92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1616656/jmcollin92), I wrote the following in SO Documentation, now transcribed here.

## X-Request-ID

### nginx

Reverse proxies can detect if a client provides a X-Request-ID header, and pass it on to the backend server. If no such header is provided, it can provide a random value.

```
map $http_x_request_id $reqid {                                                 
    default   $http_x_request_id;                                               
    ""        $request_id;                                                      
}
```

The code above stores the Request ID in the variable `$reqid` from where it can be subsequently used in logs.

```
log_format trace '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '        
                 '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" ' 
                 '"$http_x_forwarded_for" $reqid';
```

It should also be passed on to the backend services

```
location @proxy_to_app {
    proxy_set_header X-Request-ID $reqid;
    proxy_pass   http://backend;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_trace.log trace;
}
```

Comment: map cannot be used inside another block.. Rendering it useless in sub config files

Comment: To clarify further on @Tofandel's comment, it can still be used for vairables that are themselves used in a nested block, as map is lazily evaluated. The only caveat is that the map itself needs to be specified at top level.