# How to add headers in nginx only sometimes

Tags: nginx, cache-control

I have a nginx proxy to a API server. The API sometimes sets the cache control header. If the API hasnt set the cache control I want nginx to override it.

How do I do that?

I think I want to do something like this, but it doesnt work.

```
location /api {
  if ($sent_http_cache_control !~* "max-age=90") {
    add_header Cache-Control no-store;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    add_header Cache-Control private;
  }
  proxy_pass $apiPath;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify, you want to override the header if it has not been set by the upstream, or if it does not contain `max-age=90`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add header conditionally in nginx configuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467671/how-can-i-add-header-conditionally-in-nginx-configuration)

Comment: Thanks @IvanTsirulev. Ideally if its not there. But I was trying to match on the value the upstream had set in that example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot use `if` here, because `if`, being a part of the rewrite module, is evaluated at a very early stage of the request processing, way before `proxy_pass` is called and the header is returned from the upstream server.

One way to solve your problem is to use `map` directive. Variables defined with `map` are evaluated only when they are used, which is exactly what you need here. Sketchily, your configuration in this case would look like this:

```
# When the $custom_cache_control variable is being addressed
# look up the value of the Cache-Control header held in
# the $upstream_http_cache_control variable
map $upstream_http_cache_control $custom_cache_control {

    # Set the $custom_cache_control variable with the original
    # response header from the upstream server if it consists
    # of at least one character (. is a regular expression)
    "~."          $upstream_http_cache_control;

    # Otherwise set it with this value
    default       "no-store, no-cache, private";
}

server {
    ...
    location /api {
        proxy_pass $apiPath;

        # Prevent sending the original response header to the client
        # in order to avoid unnecessary duplication
        proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;

        # Evaluate and send the right header
        add_header Cache-Control $custom_cache_control;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44761645/6346531

Answer (score 10):

Awswer from Ivan Tsirulev is correct but you don't have to use regex.

Nginx uses the first parameter of `map` as default value automatically so you don't have to add that either.

```
# Get value from Http-Cache-Control header but override it when it's empty
map $upstream_http_cache_control $custom_cache_control {
    '' "no-store, no-cache, private";
}

server {
    ...
    location /api {
        # Use the value from map
        add_header Cache-Control $custom_cache_control;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The NGINX docs say that if `default` is not specified then the value will be an empty string. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html