# How to use the response header from an upstream host but also provide a default value?

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx conf which I pair with various applications to act as a reverse proxy.

I would like to enforce some specific response headers but allow the upstream service the freedom to override them.

If the inheritance rules for nginx were different, I would do something like

```
        if ($sent_http_x_content_length = '') {
            add_header X-Content-Length "nosniff" always;
        }
        if ($sent_http_content_type = '') {
            add_header Content-Type "text/html" always;
        }
```

But of course, since it's inside the `if`, the previous `if` blocks are overwritten.

What is a good workaround that doesn't involve installing the `headers-more` module?

Comment: possible answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583501/nginx-how-to-add-header-if-it-is-not-set/44761645)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I went with the nginx-plus officially sanctioned `more_set_headers` community module.

```
map $sent_http_x_powered_by $resp_x_powered_by {
    default   $sent_http_x_powered_by;
    ""        "x powered by is empty";
}
map $sent_http_x_foo $resp_x_foo {
    default   "x foo by is set";
    ""        "x foo by is empty";
}

server {
  add_header "SomeHeader" "SomeValue";
  ...
  location / {
    more_set_headers "X-Powered-By: $resp_x_powered_by";
    more_set_headers X-Foo $resp_x_foo;
  }
```

How this works:

1. `more_set_headers` will overwrite the headers that you specify with the value provided, e.g. `$resp_x_powered_by`
2. The `map` block will evaluate `$resp_x_powered_by` by looking at the string in `$sent_http_x_powered_by`.
3. If the string is `""` then we use the default value of `"x powered by is empty"`. Otherwise, we use the value from the upstream server.

Why I did this:

- Initially I tried to use `add_headers` with `map` as Raul suggested, but the issue lies in header duplication. If the header is set, then `add_header` will simply add another line to define the header again. A common workaround is to use `proxy_hide_header` but that blanks out the value so when we hit the `map` block, it will always evaluate to `""`.
- As you can see, there is an `add_header` block outside of the `location` block which would be overridden by scope inheritance. There are ways to get around it but `more_set_headers` solves that issue.